# Is a visa needed for layover or getting to the connecting flight?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, paperwork

I have a South African passport (valid until 2021) and a Portuguese passport valid until 13 Feb 2018. I am flying to Cape Verde via Paris and Lisbon, with short layovers on both. Do I need to apply for visas if I am not leaving the airport and just walking to the connecting flight check-in areas?

Comment: As the flight from Paris to Lisbon is an internal Schengen flight, you need to pass into the Schengen area of the airport and for that you would need visa. Your Portuguese passport will do instead. (As long as you have a valid Portuguese passport when you travel.)

Comment: So, unless you're traveling almost immediately, better renew your Portuguese passport.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your Portuguese passport at the French and Portuguese border, as you'll enter Schengen - a single country for border purposes - in Paris, and exit in Lisbon.

Thus, the Portuguese passport is also the one to present at check-in.

It has to be valid on the day you enter France (and Portugal on the way back) in order for check-in staff in South Africa/Cape Verde to let you board.

Otherwise, you have to renew your Portuguese passport or get a Portuguese ID card.